# How do I pop up the description and inputs of a function in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am talking about this little while line that tells me what to write next. It clearly states that I have to input data, then number of rows, then number of columns on so on and so on.

[image]

This is very helpful to know since plenty of functions like `c` doesn't pop out automatically when pressing "tab" like `matrix` does in the picture posted.

[image]

Comment: Press `ALT+SHIFT+K` and look for the shortcut.(Assuming you're using default bindings) but you can also see them(the args) with just TAB although less useful.

Comment: `c` is(citation needed) a special case for which you can only find available args by reading the documentation. It seems to only accept `...`(which is kind of everything) but it does have some other options that won't pop up even with `TAB`.

Answer (score 1):

Push tab inside the function and for most packages you can scroll through the input options!